# emacs haskell-unicode-input-method in haskell-mode convert unicode back to ascii

Tags: haskell, emacs, unicode, haskell-mode

I just started using haskell-mode for emacs and am using `turn-on-haskell-unicode-input-method`, a function that converts various expressions to unicode equivalents in the `haskell-mode` buffers.  I was surprised to find that the ascii values are permanently replaced by the unicode characters, so when trying to load into ghci REPL there are errors.  I like the unicode though, and am looking for a quick fix that converts the unicode back to ascii when saving/sending to REPL.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: GHC supports unicode symbols as identifiers if you turn on `{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling haskell mode, you can add the following snippet to your .emacs file.

```
;; Unicode symbols
(defvar haskell-font-lock-symbols)
(setq haskell-font-lock-symbols t)
```

You will be able to see the symbols, and GHC will interpret your source as a normal .hs file.

You can also check the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Unicode_symbols) for more information

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want those Unicode characters in your files, then rather than an input-method, you want some "pretty display" functionalit.  I think haskell-mode has a `haskell-font-lock-symbols` option for that.  Emacs-24.4 also introduced a similar (but global) `prettify-symbols-mode` feature for that purpose, but I don't know if haskell-mode supports it already.